# cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT)

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, cordova-plugins

I have an Ionic 3.9.2 application, which runs with cordova-android 7.0.0. Everything worked fine until I've installed cordova-plugin-datecs. Now everytime I try to execute the command `ionic cordova run android`, I get the following error:

`cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):C:\path-to-the-app\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml`

Is there any solution to solve this, apart from downgrading to a previous version of cordova-android?

What I tried so far:

- removing an reinstalling the android platform;
- installing cordova-android-support-gradle-release;
- manually creating the path res\xml (which solves this error, but creates other ones)

I understand that the problem is related to cordova changing its file structure in this version, so I guess I should be able to modify some files in the cordova-plugin-datecs to match the new structure, but I've bun unsuccessful until now.

Answer (score 2):

Solved the problem by modifying plugin.xml file. Needed to replace this line:

`<source-file src="src/android/com.datecs.api.jar" target-dir="libs" framework="true" />`

with this:

`<lib-file src="src/android/com.datecs.api.jar" arch="device" />`

Thanks to this pull request for the solutiön:

https://github.com/giorgiofellipe/cordova-plugin-datecs-printer/pull/101

Comment: I just had the exact same issue. Took me a while to debug it. I was pulling in the chartboost sdk jar file using source-file. It built fine on cordova android prior to 7.0.0 but from 7.0.0 it starts failing with the confusing could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT) message. It seems jar files must be copied using lib-file from 7.0.0